# Render a component in dymicallly created HTML element-Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, canvas

I have an angular template test.component.html

```html
<div class="container1" *ngIf="notSigned">
  <div class="div-msg wrap" [outerHTML]="htlDoc | safe: 'html'">
     
  </div>
</div>
```

and test.component.ts =>

```
import htmldemo from '../../assets/htmldemo.json';

@Component({

  selector: 'app-sign',

  templateUrl: './test.component.html',

  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss'],

  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None

})

export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  htlDoc: string = '';

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.htlDoc = "<div class=\"canvas-wrapper\" id=\"divSignpad3\"><ng-signature-pad id=\"signPad3\" [responsive]=\"true\" [height]=\"200\" placeholder=\"Hello\" doneButtonText=\"Accept\"clearButtonText=\"Clear\"  format=\"base64\" doneButtonClass=\"act-btn\" clearButtonClass=\"act-btn\" penColor=\"navy\" (cleared)=\"ClearSignature($event,'divSignpad3')\"\r\n                              (done)=\"OnSign($event,'divSignpad3')\"> <\/ng-signature-pad><\/div>"

    
  }

}
```

But  after running the application the signature-pd is not rendered  .The issue is, component is not rendering if i directly add to DOM (using innerHTML)

Comment: Any error in the console? If the view does not behave as expected, chances are high that Angular is complaining about something in the console.

Comment: No error , the signature pad dom syntax is displayed in page instead of rendering as a signature pad,<div class="canvas-wrapper" id="divSignpad1">
            <ng-signature-pad id="signPad2" [responsive]="true" [height]="200" placeholder="Hello" donebuttontext="Accept" clearbuttontext="Clear" format="base64" donebuttonclass="act-btn" clearbuttonclass="act-btn" pencolor="navy" (cleared)="ClearSignature($event,'divSignpad1')" (done)="OnSign($event,'divSignpad1')">
            </ng-signature-pad>
          </div>

Comment: Please edit your original question if you want to add info or formatted code.

Comment: Also, what about `[innerHTML]` ?

Comment: my HTML tags are getting from an API call. so i assign the response like; div.innerHTM="<ng-signature-pad id="signPad2" [responsive]="true" [height]="200" placeholder="Hello" donebuttontext="Accept" clearbuttontext="Clear" format="base64" donebuttonclass="act-btn" clearbuttonclass="act-btn" pencolor="navy" (cleared)="ClearSignature($event,'divSignpad1')" (done)="OnSign($event,'divSignpad1')"> </ng-signature-pad>"  . because i doesn't know how many signature pad should be added until API call is success

Comment: I see you are trying to render angular element `ng-signature-pad`. It just won't work. It only would work if you created web component with tag 'ng-signature-pad'. implementing that just isn't worth the effort. Try just to write all the html inside of your template

Comment: in my use case ,All the HTML  should come from database.if i create a dynamic componet 'add-sign-pad' and then if i assign to div after API call is success, like div.innerHTML='<div><add-sign-pad'></add-sign-pad'>.......' whould work ??

Comment: Again, what about `[innerHTML]` ?

Comment: If  innerHTML making any confusion then please see the forst paragraph of my post. there i used outerHTML directive to load dynamically generated HTML